# writing "dictionaries" to .csv file in a particular format after loading data allowing pickle

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, dictionary

I saved a python dictionary with the numpy np.save() function. I had to load allow_pickle to load it back so I now have the dictionary in this format:

```
values = {(0, 0, 0): {0: -1421.05, 1: -1578.94, 2: -1473.65, 3: -1471.21},(0, 0, 1): {0: -142, 1: -157, 2: -147, 3: -147},(0, 0, 2): {0: 19, 1: 15, 2: 10, 3: 12}},
```

I want to write the dictionary into csv in this format:

```
            0         1        2       3
(0,0,0):-1421.05,-1578.94,-1473.65,-1471.21
(0,0,1):-142,     -157,     -147,   -147  
(0,0,2):19,        15,        10,    12
```

Please how do I fix this?

I tried to use pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(policy)
df.to_csv('saved-policy')
```

But I keep getting below error

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVNgY.png)

Comment: I believe python `csv` has a `dict` writer.  Your error is produced while trying to make a dataframe.  You have to  read pandas to learn how to make a frame from a dict - if you want to go that way.  Your format is not valid csv.

Answer (score 0):

How about we try this?

As you represented the desired dataframe, I had to assume that the index would be a string and not a tuple.

In case I assumed wrong, please feel free to remove the single quotes from my dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd

# Change the key to strings :)

values = {'(0, 0, 0)': {0: -1421.05, 1: -1578.94, 2: -1473.65, 3: -1471.21},
'(0, 0, 1)': {0: -142, 1: -157, 2: -147, 3: -147},
'(0, 0, 2)': {0: 19, 1: 15, 2: 10, 3: 12}}

# Read the dictionary in a pd.DataFrame

df = pd.DataFrame(values)

# Transpose the dataframe

df = df.T

# Write it as .csv

df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Output:

```
                0        1        2        3
(0, 0, 0) -1421.05 -1578.94 -1473.65 -1471.21
(0, 0, 1)  -142.00  -157.00  -147.00  -147.00
(0, 0, 2)    19.00    15.00    10.00    12.00
```

Comment: Thanks Andrea, I tried doing this and I kept getting this error:--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-ddc2605dac43> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.DataFrame(var_name2)                                                                          ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=()

Comment: Hi Oluwaseyi_Ogunfowora,

can you please share the whole code that is generating the error? I am unable to reproduce it.

Also add which version of Python you're working with.

Comment: @Andrea.S  I wanted to save a python dictionary as csv to be used later. When I  couldn't figure that out, I converted the dictionary to a list and saved it as a list. (transitionprobs_view = transition_probs.items()
transitionprobs_list = list(transitionprobs_view)
transitionprobs_list). But I tried loading this back with csv.reader() with the intentions of using the dict function to convert the list of tuples back to a dict but I was getting a wrongly formated list of strings. (['(0', ' 0', " 'NM')", '1.0']
['(0', ' 1', " 'NM')", '0.648827']). How do I get a dict back from this?